# How to use & (ampersand) character in table name in dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I am using dynamic SQL to Select from a group of tables where some of the table names contain the '&' character.
However once my query hits one of these tables I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '&'.

Here is some example code that recreates the error I am getting:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME AS NVARCHAR(150);
SET @TABLE_NAME = 'A&BTable';

EXEC(
    'SELECT col1, col2, col3
     FROM Warehouse_Repository.dbo.' + @TABLE_NAME
)
```

How can I alter this query so that I can Select from table names containing '&' using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Use brackets `[]` around the name or even better - don't use special characters!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql)

```
    DECLARE @TABLE_NAME AS NVARCHAR(150);
    SET @TABLE_NAME = QUOTENAME('A&BTable');

    EXEC(
        'SELECT col1, col2, col3
         FROM dbo.' + @TABLE_NAME
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap it in block parenthesis

```
DECLARE @inputstring varchar(max)
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME AS NVARCHAR(150);
SET @TABLE_NAME = '[A&BTable]';

set @inputstring = 'select col1,col2,col3 FROM' +  @TABLE_NAME
EXEC(@inputstring)
```

Comment: `QUOTENAME` does the exact same thing, and handles the case where a table or other string might have a `]` in its name. It also has the added bonus of allowing you to define your own delimiters if need be.