# I don't really understand what is wrong

Tags: sql

Inside on create:

```
String createit = "create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,USERNAME TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT,RANK INTEGER,IDOFUSER LONG)";
String createit2 = "create table " + TABLE_NAMES +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , USERNAME TEXT , SUBJECT TEXT , MARK INTEGER)";
String createit3 = "create table " + TABLE_NAMESS +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,SUBJECT TEXT,QTITLE TEXT,QRIGHTANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT)";
String createit4 = "create table " + TABLE_NAMESSS +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TITLE TEXT,ANSWER1 TEXT,ANSWER2 TEXT,ANSWER3 TEXT,ANSWER4 TEXT,CORRECTANSWER TEXT)";

db.execSQL(createit);
db.execSQL(createit2);
db.execSQL(createit3);
db.execSQL(createit4);
```

and I get this error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "&": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table q&a (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,SUBJECT TEXT,QTITLE TEXT,QRIGHTANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
>   at com.example.finalproject.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:55)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>   at com.example.finalproject.DatabaseHelper.isuserexist(DatabaseHelper.java:249)
>   at com.example.finalproject.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

How to fix it?

Comment: Which is these four  `create table` statement is causing the error? And what values do you have in your `TABLE_NAME` through `TABLE_NAMESSS` variables?

Comment: by far if i block one table by doing // it says it about the other 3 tables that aren't TABLE_NAME. only one table has something in it because it needs to have it to insert more data.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306717/how-to-use-ampersand-character-in-table-name-in-dynamic-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use & (ampersand) character in table name in dynamic sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306717/how-to-use-ampersand-character-in-table-name-in-dynamic-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets for the special characters: & is a special character, so the brackets will help you

```
String createit = "create table [" + TABLE_NAME +"] (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,USERNAME TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT,RANK INTEGER,IDOFUSER LONG)";
String createit2 = "create table [" + TABLE_NAMES +"] (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , USERNAME TEXT , SUBJECT TEXT , MARK INTEGER)";
String createit3 = "create table [" + TABLE_NAMESS +"] (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,SUBJECT TEXT,QTITLE TEXT,QRIGHTANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT,QWRONGANSWER TEXT)";
String createit4 = "create table [" + TABLE_NAMESSS +"] (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TITLE TEXT,ANSWER1 TEXT,ANSWER2 TEXT,ANSWER3 TEXT,ANSWER4 TEXT,CORRECTANSWER TEXT)";

db.execSQL(createit);
db.execSQL(createit2);
db.execSQL(createit3);
db.execSQL(createit4);
```